# Protractor: Specified suite is not running .Instead all suite inside suites(conf.js) is running

Tags: typescript, protractor

Test Case: I wanted to run only one suite (eg) suite 'A'. So i specified the same while running configuration  protractor conf.js -- suites A

Problem: All Suites (A,B,C,D) are running, instead of just suite A.

conf.js File Excerpt:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
const HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter'); 

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,


suites:{
    // login: 'e2e/testSuites/angular.e2e-spec.ts',
    userTypeFrame:['e2e/testSuites/userTypeFrame.e2e-spec.ts'],
     //customerMyself:'e2e/testSuites/customerMyself.e2e-spec.ts',
     myselfCustomer:['e2e/testSuites/myselfCustomer.e2e-spec.ts']
},
  multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
     'chromeOptions': {
       'args': ['start-maximized']
     },
  },
  ],
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {

    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './e2e/tsconfig.json')

    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    browser.baseUrl = 'http://www.sample.domain.com';

    /*jasmin html test report */
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: 'reports/ccpa_reports',
    preserveDirectory: false, // default is true
    screenshotsSubfolder: 'screenshots',
    jsonsSubfolder: 'jsons',
    docName: 'ccpa_index.html',
    docTitle: 'CCPA TEST REPORT',
    takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: false
    }).getJasmine2Reporter()); 
  }
};
```

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/53197994/9150146

Answer (score 0):

try changing the `suites` object

```
const suites = {
    userTypeFrame: 'e2e/testSuites/userTypeFrame.e2e-spec.ts'
}
```

then `protractor conf.js --suite userTypeFrame`